# Getting "Location" header from NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can't get "Location" header from response at all. Wireshark says that i've got one:

> Location:
>   http://*/index.html#0;sid=865a84f0212a3a35d8e9d5f68398e535

But

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *hr = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
NSDictionary *dict = [hr allHeaderFields];          
NSLog(@"HEADERS : %@",[dict description]);
```

Produces this:

```
HEADERS : {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 25 Mar 2010 08:12:08 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Sat, 29 Nov 2008 15:50:54 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/0.7.59";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
}
```

No location anywhere. How to get it? I need this "sid" thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSHTTPURLResponse` is a subclass of `NSURLResponse` so you can just ask it for its `URL`. This returns an `NSURL` object from which you can get the URL components such as the query, parameter string or fragment. In your case you want the fragment component:

```
NSURL* url = [response URL];
NSString* fragment = [url fragment];
//fragment should be: 0;sid=865a84f0212a3a35d8e9d5f68398e535
```

Answer (score 3):

Thought it might be helpful to supplement @Rob Keniger's answer with an example of how to access the **Location** header in Swift. As shown above, "Location" is an HTTP response header field, so in Swift this can be done as follows:

```
if let location = response.allHeaderFields["Location"] as? String
{
    NSLog("Location \(location)")
}
```

where `response` is of type `NSHTTPURLResponse`. See [NSHTTPURLResponse Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/).