# Resolve redirect of NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a shortened URL (e.g. `t.co/12345678`). I would like to resolve the redirect without having to the load the entire page via NSURLConnection. Obviously, I can get it by sending an NSURLConnection and awaiting the response but this loads the entire page first. I am only looking for the redirect URL. Is this possible? If so, how?

=============

Edit: For posterity, here is the solution, as suggested by amleszk.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:shortenedURL
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:15.0f];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                           NSURL *resolvedURL = [httpResponse URL];
                           NSLog(@"%@", resolvedURL);
                       }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

same method as this: [finding the download size of a URL (Content-Length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779927/finding-the-download-size-of-a-url-content-length)

but you want the [NSURLResponse statusCode] = 301/302/303 and the 
Location header here: [Getting "Location" header from NSHTTPURLResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513916/getting-location-header-from-nshttpurlresponse)

Comment: Hmm, the status code returned is 200 and the http header response does not contain the redirect URL. The response URL also only contains the original URL...

Comment: Oops, it was a caching issue. Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!